# how to fix this case sql ora-01843 not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

After run sql scripts ,There's date error "ora-01843 not a valid month ", date format is (mm/dd/yyyy) this occurs on plsql, but I dont realise please see SQL statement below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT c1.end_date AS eddates,cc.effectiveto,
CASE WHEN cc.effectiveto >= '1/1/4000' THEN  '1/1/4000'
     WHEN cc.effectiveto is null THEN  '1/1/4000'
     WHEN cc.effectiveto < '1/1/4000' THEN to_char(cc.effectiveto)
  END mock_effectiveto 
from (select aa.*,b.perm_id
      from smf2.security_xref aa,
           smf2.t_security_source b
      where identifier_type_id = 4862
      and aa.security_id = b.security_id
      and b.data_source_id = 52992
      AND aa.data_source_id = 52985)c1,

      (Select bc.* 
      FROM ccc_bimbqm.instrument ab , ccc_bimbqm.identifier bc  
      WHERE bc.identifiertypepermid = 320015  
      AND ab.instrumentpermid = bc.objectpermid
      AND bc.objectpermid IN 
      (SELECT bondid FROM ccc_muni.munibonds)) cc
WHERE  c1.perm_id = cc.objectpermid
and c1.start_date = cc.effectivefrom
and cc.identifiervalue is not null
and c1.code is not NULL ) ax
WHERE ax.eddates <> mock_effectiveto
```

Comment: To ask the obvious question, does your data really have dates in the year 4000?

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: I am guessing cc.effectiveto is DATE format, in which case you need to do TO_DATE on the things you are comparing to." WHEN cc.effectiveto >= TO_DATE('1/1/4000')"

Comment: @TineO you forgot to put the format mask in your `to_date`; without that, it's a bit useless, as it relies on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter, which is the same as if you hadn't done the `to_date` in the first place. Instead it should be something like `to_date('01/01/4000', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` or even, since there's no time element required (i.e. it's set to midnight): `DATE '4000-01-01'`

Comment: @Boneist: you should add that as an answer

Comment: @Boneist So I did, he mentioned the date format being dd/mm/yyyy but I shouldnt have taken that at face value, and besides, even if it were its still best practice to put in the format. Thanks for spotting my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can update your CASE statement as -

```
CASE WHEN cc.effectiveto = TO_DATE('01/01/4000', 'MM/DD/YYYY') OR cc.effectiveto is null
          THEN TO_DATE('01/01/4000', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     WHEN cc.effectiveto < TO_DATE('01/01/4000', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          THEN to_char(cc.effectiveto)
END mock_effectiveto
```

Comment: Year must be between -4713 and +9999, so 4000 is possible

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Accepted and updated the answer.